2024 Community Moderator Election Results
Moderator election #5 on Geographic Information Systems has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:


They will be joining the existing crew shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here or view a summary report online.

Congratulations on your election Taras and HeikkiVesanto!  Your experience and expertise as long term users of GIS and GIS SE will be invaluable for the moderation of this site.

Indeed - congratulations to both

Congrats to you both welcome to the fun of moderation.

Congrats to the winners.

Congratulations! Excellent choices for new moderators!

Thanks everyone who voted! Happy to do my part to support the community.

Congratulations!

Thank you, dear community, for each vote you trusted in me
